# How to write SQL window functions in pandas

Tags: python, sql, pandas, dataframe, window-functions

Is there an idiomatic equivalent to SQL's window functions in Pandas? For example, what's the most compact way to write the equivalent of this in Pandas?

```sql
SELECT state_name,  
       state_population,
       SUM(state_population)
        OVER() AS national_population
FROM population   
ORDER BY state_name
```

Or this?:

```sql
SELECT state_name,  
       state_population,
       region,
       SUM(state_population)
        OVER(PARTITION BY region) AS regional_population
FROM population    
ORDER BY state_name
```

Comment: Can you provide a sample data set and desired data set?

Comment: @JackManey, AFAIK it's not quite the same - at least for mentioned SQLs...

Comment: @JackManey the window functions in the Pandas docs are a subset of the functionality that SQL window functions have. Basically what I want to do is compute aggregates without reducing the data frame.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

For the first SQL:

```
SELECT state_name,  
       state_population,
       SUM(state_population)
        OVER() AS national_population
FROM population   
ORDER BY state_name
```

Pandas:

```
df.assign(national_population=df.state_population.sum()).sort_values('state_name')
```

For the second SQL:

```
SELECT state_name,  
       state_population,
       region,
       SUM(state_population)
        OVER(PARTITION BY region) AS regional_population
FROM population    
ORDER BY state_name
```

Pandas:

```
df.assign(regional_population=df.groupby('region')['state_population'].transform('sum')) \
  .sort_values('state_name')
```

**DEMO:**

```
In [238]: df
Out[238]:
   region state_name  state_population
0       1        aaa               100
1       1        bbb               110
2       2        ccc               200
3       2        ddd               100
4       2        eee               100
5       3        xxx                55
```

national_population:

```
In [246]: df.assign(national_population=df.state_population.sum()).sort_values('state_name')
Out[246]:
   region state_name  state_population  national_population
0       1        aaa               100                  665
1       1        bbb               110                  665
2       2        ccc               200                  665
3       2        ddd               100                  665
4       2        eee               100                  665
5       3        xxx                55                  665
```

regional_population:

```
In [239]: df.assign(regional_population=df.groupby('region')['state_population'].transform('sum')) \
     ...:   .sort_values('state_name')
Out[239]:
   region state_name  state_population  regional_population
0       1        aaa               100                  210
1       1        bbb               110                  210
2       2        ccc               200                  400
3       2        ddd               100                  400
4       2        eee               100                  400
5       3        xxx                55                   55
```

Comment: Thanks, this is what I was looking for. Didn't know about `transform`.

Comment: @2daaa, you are welcome. You may want to read [Pandas: comparison with SQL](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/comparison_with_sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

Another common window is `OVER(ORDER BY ...)`. For example, the following.

```sql
SELECT *
    ,SUM(values) OVER(ORDER BY date) AS cum_sum
FROM df;
```

The pandas equivalent is `cumsum()`

```py
df['cum_sum'] = df['values'].sort_values(by='date').cumsum()
```

Another common window function is `ROW_NUMBER()`.

```sql
SELECT *
    ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER () AS row_number
FROM df;
```

It's equivalent pandas equivalent is `range()`.

```py
df['row_number'] = range(1, len(df)+1)
```

---

Also there is a module `pandasql` that's built on pandas that lets you run sql queries on local dataframes. So if you're comfortable with sql, then you can run a query directly on a dataframe.

```py
# !pip isntall pandasql
from pandasql import sqldf
df = sqldf("""
SELECT state_name,  
       state_population,
       SUM(state_population)
        OVER() AS national_population
FROM population   
ORDER BY state_name 
""")
```